# A little confusion about DBM files and how they work

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have apache 2.4 and am using RewriteMap DBM files.

ie:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap examplemap "dbm:/etc/httpd/conf/rewrite.dbm"
    RewriteCond ${examplemap:$1} !=""
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /${examplemap:$1} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/me
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RewriteMap redirects "dbm:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.dbm"
    RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
    RewriteRule ^(/.*) /${redirects:$1} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to be able to prove that the second dbm file (redirects.dbm) is not being loaded into memory when a request is made and the condition is found in the first dbm file (rewrite.dbm)

To my knowledge on the various reading I have done both files are loaded into memory. IS that correct?

The reason for this is the rewrite.dbm will only contain about 300 rewrites however will change frequently (daily). The redirects.dbm will never change once loaded and will contain about 30,000 redirects.

The client wants to make sure that the second DBM files will not be loaded into memory and/or slow the request time down if the first dbm file is all that is needed.

I think the flow would go something like this:

http://example.com/abc

IF /abc is in rewrite.dbm end and show page

IF /abc is not in rewrite.dbm search redirects.dbm

IF /abc not in either throw 404

Hope what I am asking is clear.